# Sitecore Images appearing in Chrome but appear broken in FF and IE

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've recently upgraded my dev, beta, and live environments to Sitecore 6.5. On my dev environment site-wide images appear in all browsers. However, my beta (hosted) environment only shows images in Chrome, and broken images FF or IE. I've tried copying my /App_Data/MediaFiles folder over to beta and deleted /App_Data/MediaCache, but it did not resolve the problem. I also did a site-wide publish on beta with no results. Am I missing something? My web.config files on each are almost identical.

Comment: Broken images means broken links or there is some other problems with images? Are you sure the images are not cached in chrome?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and see if it is solves the issue.

Comment: Can you browse to the image ashx directly in any of the browsers? What if you pass in additional url parameters like `mw` (maxwidth) or `mh` (maxheight)? Have you checked your Sitecore log files in beta?

Comment: Please paste a full URL for an image that isn't working in FF but is in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- As stated by the previous user, double check your cache, even recycle your app pool to force things through
- check your web database just to be sure your publish isn't having issues and the items do exist AND have a file associated
- download an trouble image and see if the file got corrupted.  I've had images break in IE but not firefox due to image corruption
- lastly, and I don't think it is the cause because it works in Chrome, but check your mime types in IIS and your web.config to see if all your image extensions are allowed.